# Rendering form in a model: undefined method `host_with_port' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm rendering a partial containing a form in a model.
Well that is may be not the most obvious thing to do but still: that is what I'm trying.

### Rationale:

Let me first motivate why I'm doing it (so as if you have suggestions of doing another way, please feel free):

I'm building a simple messaging functionality for the users of my app so that when they need to perform an action, they are notified through a message and the message contains the data and the actions to be performed.

An example: users are receiving invitation to join a given group. The invitation contains the name of the owner of the group, the name of the group and two buttons to accept or ignore the invitation.

### The code:

Here is the message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.group_invitation(group, user)
    @m=Message.new({
                     :status => :unread,
                     :from_user_id => group.owner.id,
                     :to_user_id => user.id,
                     :type => :group_invitation,
                     :title => "Invitation to the group: #{group.name}.",
                     :message => ActionController::Base.new.send(:render_to_string,
                                :partial => 'messages/group_invitation',
                                            :locals => {:group => group,
                                                        :user => user}
                                                                 )
                  })
    @m.save!
  end
end
```

Here is the partial I'm rendering in the model (i.e. 'messages/group_invitation'):

```
<div>
  <h1> Invitation to <%= group.name %> </h1>
  <p>
    Hello <%= user.name %>,
  </p>
  <p>
    You have been invited by <%= group.owner.name %> to join the group
    <%= group.name %>.
  </p>
</div>

<div>
Please take one of the following action:
<br/>
     <%=  m= group.memberships.find_by_user_id(user.id)
       m.status = :validated
       render 'memberships/form', :membership => m, :method =>
       :put, :label => "Accept" %>
<br/>
    <%= render 'memberships/form', :membership => m, :method =>
      :delete, :label => "Ignore" %>
</div>
```

where the 'membership/form' partial is:

```
<%= form_for membership, :html => {:method => method} do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :group_id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :status %>
 <%= f.submit :value => label %>
<% end %>
```

The user has a membership to the group that is created when the invitation is sent with the status 'invited'. The user will receive an internal message with in it the ability to update the membership to the 'validated' status.

Without the form the invitation is correctly produced but with the form, I get the following error at the first line of the 'membership/form' partial:

```
undefined method `host_with_port' for nil:NilClass
```

I assume I have to include/require the definition of the urlherlpers somewhere in order the render produce the correct paths etc. But my attempts to do so did not yield any success.

So if there is some clever guy looking at it, may be he will be so kind to give me some ideas to solve this.

Many thank in anticipation

Comment: Actually, I get the same error when I try to render a 'link_to' statement. I'll dig further in this direction ;-)

Comment: I observe that the `host_with_port` method is called at the building of the url on the `request` object (in `action_controller/meta/url_for`)  . I assume I have to feed this `request` object in a way or another.